# How to compare the first tuple from one list of tuples with the first from another list, then the second with the second list, and so on?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, iteration

I'm trying to compare two lists of tuples made of integers and I cannot seem to succeed.
list_a = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1)]
list_b = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1)]

I'm trying to compare the first tuple with the first tuple of the other list, then the second with the second, then the third and so on.

I tried to loop through the two lists and values, like below.

```py
for w, x in list_a: 
    for y, z in list_b:
        if x == z:
            total += 1
            break
        else:
            total -= 1
            break
```

In the first loop, the variables "w" and "x" from value will get the values: (1, 1). Then "y" and "z" will get (1, 2) and will compare. So far so good.
My problem is that then "y" and "z" will loop through the second tuple of list_b, whilst "w" and "x" will remain with the first tuple of list_a

I hope this is understandable, I'm sorry, I have good english knowledge but sometimes it's a little hard to explain this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `zip()` them together so you can compare the values of the entire tuple in one list iterate:

```
list_a = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1)] 
list_b = [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1)]

total = 0
for (w, x), (y, z) in zip(list_a, list_b):
    # (w, x) are from list_a
    # (y, z) are from list_b
    if x == z:
        total += 1
    else:
        total -= 1
```